# constructing a matrix in matlab using if, elseif and else

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, for-else

Can anyone help me with this. I am trying to construct a matrix in matlab using if, elseif and else but it does not work for me. If I skip the last else everything works correctly but if I run everything, including the last else sentence, elseif `N==L(i)` and elseif `N==R(i)` does not work. So if I skip the last else sentence `if N==1`,   `elseif N>=2 && N<=4`,  `elseif N>=5 && N<=9`, `elseif N==L(i)` and `elseif R==L(i)` runs correctly but if I run everything elseif `N==L(i)` and elseif `R==L(i)` does not work.

```
N = 72; 
M = 72;
adj = zeros(N,M)
L = [10:7:M-13]
R = [16:7:M-7]




for N = 1:M
    for i = 1:ceil((M-10)/15)

    if N==1
        adj(1,2:4)= 1

    elseif N>=2 && N<=4

              adj(N,(N+3))=1
              adj(N,(N+4))=1
              adj(N,(N+5))=1

      elseif N>=5 && N<=9

              adj(N,(N+5))=1
              adj(N,(N+6))=1
              adj(N,(N+7))=1

      elseif N==L(i)

              adj(N,N+7)=1
              adj(N,N+8)=1


      elseif N==R(i)

              adj(N,N+6)=1
              adj(N,N+7)=1

    else
              adj(N,N+6)=1
              adj(N,N+7)=1
              adj(N,N+8)=1    
    end


    end
end
```

Comment: What's the output _supposed_ to be? From the output I get it seems it would be simpler to work backwards - just generate a tridiagonal matrix and remove a few rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a switch case statement

```
N = 72; 
M = 72;
adj = zeros(N,M);
L = [10:7:M-13];
R = [16:7:M-7];

for N = 1:M
    for i = 1:ceil((M-10)/15)

        switch(N)

            case {1}
               adj(1,2:4)= 1;

            case {2:4}
              adj(N,(N+3))=1;
              adj(N,(N+4))=1;
              adj(N,(N+5))=1;

            case {5:9}
              adj(N,(N+5))=1;
              adj(N,(N+6))=1;
              adj(N,(N+7))=1;

            case {L(i)}
              adj(N,N+7)=1;
              adj(N,N+8)=1;

            case {R(i)}
              adj(N,N+6)=1;
              adj(N,N+7)=1;

            otherwise
              adj(N,N+6)=1;
              adj(N,N+7)=1;
              adj(N,N+8)=1;  
            end


    end
end
```

This gives a slightly different answer to your code. Note that only the first satisfying `case` will be triggered. So if both `{5:9}` and `{L(i)}` are true, only the `{5:9}` case will be triggered.

Also, it may be just a typo, or me not understanding the wording, but you are writing `R==L(i)` in your description but that doesn't appear in your code.

Edit:
From your comment below, it seems you want more than one `elseif` or `case` statement to be triggered at a time. In this case, neither a series of `elseif`s or `case`s will work. Simply replace all the `elseif`s with separate, indivdiual `if` statements, without any `elseif`s. Just be aware that now any `if` statement can trigger, including the ones you don't intend to. So you will have to look carefully at each condition.

Comment: Sorry this was just typo, I have edited my question. But this seems to give exactly the same result and the same problem is occurring, because if both {L(i)} and the otherwise statement are true only the otherwise statement is triggered but not {L(i)} as it is supposed to and the same with {R(i)}, only the otherwise statement is triggered but no the {R(i)}.